# Why is the static java.util.Collections.fill() method declared in java.util.Collections rather than an instance method in java.util.AbstractList?

Tags: java, collections

In `java.util.Collections`, there is a method:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)
```

that fills the `List` specified by the first parameter with the object specified by the second parameter. To call this method, once could write, for example:

```
java.util.List<String> l;
//...
java.util.Collections.fill(l, "Hello");
```

Why was this method not declared as an instance method in `java.util.AbstractList`? If it were, it could have been made as an instance method, and it would seem to be more convenient to call it as:

```
java.util.List<String> l;
//...
l.fill("Hello");
```

Comment: You could ask the same question for every method in the Collections utility class. Like `sort` or `shuffle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there exist other classes than `AbstractList` that implement the interface `List`. One example from the Java library is [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), and anyone could make their own implementation as well. Thus, by accepting `List`, the method is more useful because it can work with any of these classes.

Comment: Good answer, except that Vector does in fact extend AbstractList.  A better example would be [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: @VGR: Gah, I used the wrong mode in my type hierarchy inspector. Thanks; I used your suggestion.

Comment: But, now that we have `default` methods, `fill` could be made into a `default` method of the `java.util.List` class and this problem would be solved. Do you agree?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: Yes. However, default methods were not available at the time when `fill()` was created, and now that the method is there, it can't be removed without breaking a lot of existing code. They could have added it as a default method, but I'm guessing they chose not to because the improvement would be very minor.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Yes, it was a hypothetical question, of course, `default` methods were not available at the time. However, I don't think the improvement would be minor. It's not exactly intuitive to find a `fill()` method for `List`s in a `Collections` class. Moreover, using an IDE, developers will not see the `fill()` method when they type `.` on an object reference and may very well write their **own** `fill()` method or equivalent inline code.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: Good point; looking in `Collections` is non-obvious for someone who's new to Java. Let me put it this way, then: there were many other improvements that were more important, and this one was not prioritized by Oracle (if they thought about it at all).

Answer (score 2):

There are other Lists as `java.util.AbstractList`. You can even create your own, all new List implementation.

`java.util.Collections.fill();` will work on all implementations, not just on `AbstactList`s.

Comment: But if you create your own list, can't you extend `java.util.AbstractList`?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian You can extend `java.util.AbstractList` if you want. But even if you don't you still can use `java.util.Collections.fill()`. That's great, isn't it? The makers of java chose to give you this flexibility (that you would not have anymore, if the method had been declared in `java.util.AbstractList`).

Comment: Yes, I agree the flexibility is key, however, a method like `fill()` really should be an instance method. I pointed out a few reasons in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose its for possibility to work with any implementation of `java.util.List` interface, not only `java.util.AbstractList` children. 
Assuming I have my implementation of List, not derived from AbstractList, with your design I have to implement this method by myself.